# If $NP \ne coNP$, $L_1, L_2 \in NP$, then is it necessary for $\bar{L_1} \cap L_2 \in NP$ and checking the proof of $P \ne NP$

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

I am a beginner in the computer science track.
I have some problems with the following problems

**Problem 1:** Assume that $NP \ne coNP$. If $L_1, L_2 \in NP$, is $\bar{L_1} \cap L_2$ necessarily in $coNP$.

**My attempt:** I intend to choose $L_1, L_2$ such that $L_1= \emptyset $, $L_2$ is in $NP$ complete. Then $\bar{L_1} \cap L_2 = L_2$. $L_2$ is in $NP$ complete.
Becaues $NP \ne coNP$ then the complement of $L_2$ (denoted by $\overline{L_2}$) is not in $NP$.
Then $L_2$ is not in $coNP$.

Could you please help me with checking my work?

**Problem 2:** What is wrong with the following proof of $P \neq N P$ ?

Suppose that $P=NP$. Then, there exists an algorithm $A$ and a polynomial $p(n)$ such that SAT is decided by $A$ in time $O(p(n))$. Assume that $p(n)=O\left(n^{37}\right)$. By the Time Hierarchy Theorem, there exists a problem $P \in \operatorname{DTIME}\left(n^{38}\right)$ such that $P \notin \operatorname{DTIME}\left(n^{37} \log n^{37}\right)=$ DTIME $\left(n^{37} \log n\right)$. Since SAT is NP-complete, we can reduce $P$ to SAT and decide it in time $O\left(n^{37}\right)$. But we have just shown that $P$ requires time $\omega\left(n^{37} \log n\right)$. This leads to a contradiction, hence the assumption $\mathrm{P}=$ NP must be false.

**My attempts:** I think the proof is wrong because based on Time Hierarchy Theorem, we have
$$\operatorname{DTIME}(o(n^{37})) \subsetneq \operatorname{DTIME}(n^{37}  \log n^{37} )$$

So I think that the statement: "there exists a problem $P \in \operatorname{DTIME}\left(n^{38}\right)$ such that $P \notin \operatorname{DTIME}\left(n^{37} \log n^{37}\right)=$ DTIME $\left(n^{37} \log n\right)$ " is a wrong statement.

Could you kindly verify my assessment of this proof and offer any further insights you may have on the matter? I genuinely appreciate your time and assistance in helping me navigate these challenging problems.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  We generally discourage "please check whether my answer is correct", as the answer is unlikely to be useful to future visitors.